# Hadoop - install process for /usr/libexec etc

Tags: macos, hadoop, installation

I'm trying to compile/install/run Hadoop as a single node cluster on a Mac OS X 10.7.5.
I've downloaded the hadoop-2.2.0-src, and am able to compile all modules with

```
mvn install
```

The install is successful, and the tests check out too.

When trying to run hadoop (specifically, hdfs -namenode format to start off with), I see a requirement for hadoop components to exist in directories like:

```
/usr/libexec
/usr/lib/conf etc.
```

What is the install step required to get the files into this directory? Can it be done from Maven, or is there a manual install step required?

One option, and I'm not sure if it's correct, is to set my HADOOP_HOME - is this where hadoop finds its /libexecs?

Thanks guys
Pete